# Binance Signature for this request is not valid error

Tags: node.js, sha256, binance

I'm trying to make [this](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#margin-account-new-order-trade) work

Here's the error I get:

```
data: { code: -1022, msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.' }
```

Functions

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

export async function signature (query_string) {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret).update(query_string).digest('hex')
}

export async function order (symbol, quantity, price) {    
  const query = '?symbol=' + symbol + '&isIsolated=TRUE&side=BUY&quantity=' + quantity + '&price=' + price + '&type=LIMIT&sideEffectType=MARGIN_BUY&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=' + Date.now()

  const querySigned = await signature(query)

  const sendingQuery = query + '&signature=' + querySigned

  const queryConfig = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/margin/order/' + sendingQuery,
    headers: {
      'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey,
    },
  }

  const response = await axios(queryConfig)

  return response.data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't include the question mark in the input for signature.

```
const query = 'symbol=' + symbol +  // removed the question mark
```

```
const queryConfig = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/margin/order/?' + sendingQuery,  // added the question mark
    headers: {
      'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey,
    },
}
```

Source: I looked up my old code from a year ago that was also using the Binance API and found a difference in the question mark (not) passed as the signature input.

---

I used it for a spot order but I'll still include it. Maybe it will help you debug further if this is not a correct solution.

```
let query = 'recvWindow=5000&timestamp='+(new Date().getTime()) + "&symbol=" + baseAsset + quoteAsset + "&side=" + side + "&quantity=" + baseAmount + "&type=market";
const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret).update(query).digest("hex");
query += '&signature='+signature;

const result = await axios({
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?'+query,
    'headers': {
        'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried removing the question mark from the signature input, then added it to url, now it says "msg: 'A mandatory parameter was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed.'" Thanks, though.

Comment: Timestamp and a signature, respectively, should be the last two parameters in url string. Just change the order of url parameters.